# Meteor using Azure MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, azure, meteor, azure-cosmosdb

Is it possible, and if so how, to use an Azure MongoDB as the backend for my Meteor Application.
I have added the connection string from my database into the MONGO_URL variable with no success. I have found some previous threads over Stack Overflow and on here about incompatibility related to oplog errors, but they seem to be using DocumentDB instead of Azure's MongoDB (which I think is newer than a few years ago).

[image: Mongo Option]

Comment: You *are* using DocumentDB, just with MongoDB compatibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, you're actually using DocumentDB with MongoDB compatibility. You're not using native MongoDB (nor is this native MongoDB as-a-service).

DocumentDB (even with MongoDB compat) does not provide an oplog. And since Meteor has a dependency on reading the oplog, you wouldn't be able to point Meteor at DocumentDB.

In your case, you'd need to either run native MongoDB on your own (e.g. in VMs) or take advantage of a 3rd-party MongoDB hosting solution which provides MongoDB support within the same region as your app. (ok, yes, you can run your app in a different region, but you'd see latency along with data egress charges).

Comment: Or disable oplog and use a package like [redis-oplog](https://github.com/cult-of-coders/redis-oplog)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'ts been a while. May I ask if this limitation still applies to the current Azure CosmosDB API for Meteor?

Comment: @jenszo - Cosmos DB's MongoDB API does not expose an oplog (as there is no oplog). The MongoDB API now supports change streams, so if Meteor supports change streams, you could try that...