# Meteor application MongoDB connection timed out with Azure DocumentDB database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, azure-cosmosdb

I'm running a Meteor application with on the top of Nginx server with separate MongoDB database. In configuration file I set `MONGO_URL` as:

```
"MONGO_URL":"mongodb://user:password@host:port/dbName”
```

I've created MongoDB in Mizrosoft Azure as NoSQL DocumentDB. When I start Nginx to run the app it shows following error in the log file:

```
MongoError: connection 0 to HOST:10250 timed out
App 47594 stderr:     at Object.Future.wait (DIRECTORY/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:449:15)
App 47594 stderr:     at new MongoConnection (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:217:27)
App 47594 stderr:     at new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver (packages/mongo/remote_collection_driver.js:4:16)
App 47594 stderr:     at Object.<anonymous> (packages/mongo/remote_collection_driver.js:38:10)
App 47594 stderr:     at Object.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver (packages/underscore.js:784:19)
App 47594 stderr:     at new Mongo.Collection (packages/mongo/collection.js:99:40)
App 47594 stderr:     at AccountsServer.AccountsCommon (packages/accounts-base/accounts_common.js:23:18)
App 47594 stderr:     at new AccountsServer (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:18:5)
App 47594 stderr:     at meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor.accounts-base.server_main.js (packages/accounts-base/server_main.js:9:12)
App 47594 stderr:     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:197:9)
App 47594 stderr:     - - - - -
App 47594 stderr:     at Function.MongoError.create (DIRECTORY/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:29:11)
App 47594 stderr:     at Socket.<anonymous> (DIRECTORY/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:184:20)
App 47594 stderr:     at Socket.g (events.js:260:16)
App 47594 stderr:     at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
App 47594 stderr:     at Socket.emit (events.js:166:7)
App 47594 stderr:     at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:333:8)
App 47594 stderr:     at _runOnTimeout (timers.js:537:11)
App 47594 stderr:     at _makeTimerTimeout (timers.js:528:3)
App 47594 stderr:     at Timer.unrefTimeout (timers.js:597:5)
```

Is there any problem with the way I defined MONGO_URL ?

Comment: Take a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42545911/272109). I'm not sure of your *exact* issue above, but you won't be able to run a Meteor app with DocumentDB (even with MongoDB compatibility).

Comment: That's helpful. So, the conclusion is Azure hosted MongoDB(don't support  oplog tailing) is still not usable in Meteor app.

Comment: No - not accurate. Remember that DocumentDB is a native database service, and is not MongoDB. You can easily host MongoDB in Azure VMs with no issues with using the oplog (because it will be 100% MongoDB). Your issue is specifically with DocumentDB using MongoDB compatibility mode, which doesn't expose an oplog. Note: DocumentDB does have a *change feed*, but it's not the same as MongoDB's oplog.

Comment: Opps, I concluded wrong, I see!  Anyway, DocumentDB service can't be used for Database in Meteor application, right?