# Azure DocumentDB and Meteor Accounts

Tags: mongodb, meteor, azure-cosmosdb

My Meteor app is connected to a DocumentDB database, I try to create a Meteor Accounts using Accounts.createUser({}) , but I can't login to the user because I have been logged  out automatically.  and the  resume.TokenLogin are not removed from the database.
I try to compare that behavior with the local MongoDB one, I found that in local MongoDB some collections are created: **users**, 
  **meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration** and  **system.indexes** but in the docuementDB just users and meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration are created.

I don't khnow if the problem is related with the collection system.indexes or if I need to add somethings to not been logged out automatically after each authentification !

Comment: Could you connect meteor application to the DocumentDB database? I'm wondering as I couldn't do this previously [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42740317/1067326).

Comment: This really seems like a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42542437/meteor-using-azure-mongodb) that I answered a while back. Meteor depends on the oplong, which Cosmos DB (mongodb) doesn't expose.

Comment: @mostafizrahman - please also look at the answer I linked to. I don't know if it's the exact same issue you had, but, might help.

Comment: As David said, [Meteor uses oplog](https://meteorhacks.com/mongodb-oplog-and-meteor/), but Cosmos DB (MongoDB) doesn't provide oplog, if possible, you could host MongoDB in Azure VMs.